# Add a content type (like Drupal) in magento

Tags: drupal, magento-1.7, drupal-content-types

I am a Drupal Developer and now days I am also working on magneto. I want to add a custom content type in a magento store. The fields of custom content type are completely different from "products" and i don't want to use "products" for this purpose. Also I want to add different content types other than product.

So do you have any idea how i can achieve this ?